# Using bluebird with socket.io not working

Tags: node.js, socket.io, bluebird

I am using simple socket.io chat example http://socket.io/get-started/chat/

And then trying to apply bluebird like this:

```
Promise.promisifyAll(io);

io.onAsync('connection')
.then(function(socket){
  console.log('a user connected');
  return socket.onAsync('chat message');
})
.then(function(msg){
  return io.emitAsync('chat message',msg)
})
.catch(function(error){
  console.log("something happened here")
  console.log(error);
});
```

For some reason this does not get to any `.then` and moves straight to `.catch` upon connection and throwing this:

```
Socket {
nsp:
   Namespace {
     name: '/',
     server:
      Server {
        nsps: [Object],
        _path: '/socket.io',
        _serveClient: true,
        _adapter: [Function: Adapter],
        _origins: '*:*',
        sockets: [Circular],
        eio: [Object],
        httpServer: [Object],
        engine: [Object],
        checkRequestAsync: [Function],
        serveClientAsync: [Function],
        setAsync: [Function],
        pathAsync: [Function],
        adapterAsync: [Function],
        originsAsync: [Function],
        attachAsync: [Function],
        listenAsync: [Function],
        attachServeAsync: [Function],
        serveAsync: [Function],
        bindAsync: [Function],
        onconnectionAsync: [Function],
        ofAsync: [Function],
        closeAsync: [Function],
        onAsync: [Function],
        toAsync: [Function],
        inAsync: [Function],
        useAsync: [Function],
        emitAsync: [Function],
        sendAsync: [Function],
        writeAsync: [Function],
        clientsAsync: [Function],
        compressAsync: [Function] },
     sockets: { '/#gePE_87A58Q80T9rAAAA': [Circular] },
     connected: { '/#gePE_87A58Q80T9rAAAA': [Circular] },
     fns: [],
     ids: 0,
     adapter:
      Adapter {
        nsp: [Circular],
        rooms: [Object],
        sids: [Object],
        encoder: Encoder {} },
     _events: { connection: [Function] },
     _eventsCount: 1 },
  server:
   Server {
     nsps: { '/': [Object] },
     _path: '/socket.io',
     _serveClient: true,
     _adapter: [Function: Adapter],
     _origins: '*:*',
     sockets:
      Namespace {
        name: '/',
        server: [Circular],
        sockets: [Object],
        connected: [Object],
        fns: [],
        ids: 0,
        adapter: [Object],
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 1 },
     eio:
      Server {
        clients: [Object],
        clientsCount: 1,
        pingTimeout: 60000,
        pingInterval: 25000,
        upgradeTimeout: 10000,
        maxHttpBufferSize: 100000000,
        transports: [Object],
        allowUpgrades: true,
        allowRequest: [Function: bound ],
        cookie: 'io',
        cookiePath: false,
        perMessageDeflate: [Object],
        httpCompression: [Object],
        ws: [Object],
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 1 },
     httpServer:
      Server {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 5,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _connections: 3,
        _handle: [Object],
        _usingSlaves: false,
        _slaves: [],
        _unref: false,
        allowHalfOpen: true,
        pauseOnConnect: false,
        httpAllowHalfOpen: false,
        timeout: 120000,
        _pendingResponseData: 0,
        _connectionKey: '6::::3000' },
     engine:
      Server {
        clients: [Object],
        clientsCount: 1,
        pingTimeout: 60000,
        pingInterval: 25000,
        upgradeTimeout: 10000,
        maxHttpBufferSize: 100000000,
        transports: [Object],
        allowUpgrades: true,
        allowRequest: [Function: bound ],
        cookie: 'io',
        cookiePath: false,
        perMessageDeflate: [Object],
        httpCompression: [Object],
        ws: [Object],
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 1 },
     checkRequestAsync: [Function],
     serveClientAsync: [Function],
     setAsync: [Function],
     pathAsync: [Function],
     adapterAsync: [Function],
     originsAsync: [Function],
     attachAsync: [Function],
     listenAsync: [Function],
     attachServeAsync: [Function],
     serveAsync: [Function],
     bindAsync: [Function],
     onconnectionAsync: [Function],
     ofAsync: [Function],
     closeAsync: [Function],
     onAsync: [Function],
     toAsync: [Function],
     inAsync: [Function],
     useAsync: [Function],
     emitAsync: [Function],
     sendAsync: [Function],
     writeAsync: [Function],
     clientsAsync: [Function],
     compressAsync: [Function] },
  adapter:
   Adapter {
     nsp:
      Namespace {
        name: '/',
        server: [Object],
        sockets: [Object],
        connected: [Object],
        fns: [],
        ids: 0,
        adapter: [Circular],
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 1 },
     rooms: { '/#gePE_87A58Q80T9rAAAA': [Object] },
     sids: { '/#gePE_87A58Q80T9rAAAA': [Object] },
     encoder: Encoder {} },
  id: '/#gePE_87A58Q80T9rAAAA',
  client:
   Client {
     server:
      Server {
        nsps: [Object],
        _path: '/socket.io',
        _serveClient: true,
        _adapter: [Function: Adapter],
        _origins: '*:*',
        sockets: [Object],
        eio: [Object],
        httpServer: [Object],
        engine: [Object],
        checkRequestAsync: [Function],
        serveClientAsync: [Function],
        setAsync: [Function],
        pathAsync: [Function],
        adapterAsync: [Function],
        originsAsync: [Function],
        attachAsync: [Function],
        listenAsync: [Function],
        attachServeAsync: [Function],
        serveAsync: [Function],
        bindAsync: [Function],
        onconnectionAsync: [Function],
        ofAsync: [Function],
        closeAsync: [Function],
        onAsync: [Function],
        toAsync: [Function],
        inAsync: [Function],
        useAsync: [Function],
        emitAsync: [Function],
        sendAsync: [Function],
        writeAsync: [Function],
        clientsAsync: [Function],
        compressAsync: [Function] },
     conn:
      Socket {
        id: 'gePE_87A58Q80T9rAAAA',
        server: [Object],
        upgrading: false,
        upgraded: false,
        readyState: 'open',
        writeBuffer: [Object],
        packetsFn: [Object],
        sentCallbackFn: [],
        cleanupFn: [Object],
        request: [Object],
        remoteAddress: '::1',
        checkIntervalTimer: null,
        upgradeTimeoutTimer: null,
        pingTimeoutTimer: [Object],
        transport: [Object],
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 3 },
     encoder: Encoder {},
     decoder: Decoder { reconstructor: null, _callbacks: [Object] },
     id: 'gePE_87A58Q80T9rAAAA',
     request:
      IncomingMessage {
        _readableState: [Object],
        readable: false,
        domain: null,
        _events: {},
        _eventsCount: 0,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        socket: [Object],
        connection: [Object],
        httpVersionMajor: 1,
        httpVersionMinor: 1,
        httpVersion: '1.1',
        complete: true,
        headers: [Object],
        rawHeaders: [Object],
        trailers: {},
        rawTrailers: [],
        upgrade: false,
        url: '/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LSa9q5d',
        method: 'GET',
        statusCode: null,
        statusMessage: null,
        client: [Object],
        _consuming: true,
        _dumped: true,
        _query: [Object],
        res: [Object],
        cleanup: [Function: cleanup],
        read: [Function] },
     onclose: [Function: bound ],
     ondata: [Function: bound ],
     onerror: [Function: bound ],
     ondecoded: [Function: bound ],
     sockets: { '/#gePE_87A58Q80T9rAAAA': [Circular] },
     nsps: { '/': [Circular] },
     connectBuffer: [] },
  conn:
   Socket {
     id: 'gePE_87A58Q80T9rAAAA',
     server:
      Server {
        clients: [Object],
        clientsCount: 1,
        pingTimeout: 60000,
        pingInterval: 25000,
        upgradeTimeout: 10000,
        maxHttpBufferSize: 100000000,
        transports: [Object],
        allowUpgrades: true,
        allowRequest: [Function: bound ],
        cookie: 'io',
        cookiePath: false,
        perMessageDeflate: [Object],
        httpCompression: [Object],
        ws: [Object],
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 1 },
     upgrading: false,
     upgraded: false,
     readyState: 'open',
     writeBuffer: [ [Object] ],
     packetsFn: [ undefined ],
     sentCallbackFn: [],
     cleanupFn: [ [Function], [Function] ],
     request:
      IncomingMessage {
        _readableState: [Object],
        readable: false,
        domain: null,
        _events: {},
        _eventsCount: 0,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        socket: [Object],
        connection: [Object],
        httpVersionMajor: 1,
        httpVersionMinor: 1,
        httpVersion: '1.1',
        complete: true,
        headers: [Object],
        rawHeaders: [Object],
        trailers: {},
        rawTrailers: [],
        upgrade: false,
        url: '/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LSa9q5d',
        method: 'GET',
        statusCode: null,
        statusMessage: null,
        client: [Object],
        _consuming: true,
        _dumped: true,
        _query: [Object],
        res: [Object],
        cleanup: [Function: cleanup],
        read: [Function] },
     remoteAddress: '::1',
     checkIntervalTimer: null,
     upgradeTimeoutTimer: null,
     pingTimeoutTimer:
      { _called: false,
        _idleTimeout: 85000,
        _idlePrev: [Object],
        _idleNext: [Object],
        _idleStart: 6060,
        _onTimeout: [Function],
        _repeat: null },
     transport:
      XHR {
        readyState: 'open',
        discarded: false,
        closeTimeout: 30000,
        maxHttpBufferSize: 100000000,
        httpCompression: [Object],
        supportsBinary: true,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 5,
        sid: 'gePE_87A58Q80T9rAAAA',
        req: null,
        res: null,
        writable: false },
     _events:
      { close: [Object],
        data: [Function: bound ],
        error: [Function: bound ] },
     _eventsCount: 3 },
  rooms: { '/#gePE_87A58Q80T9rAAAA': '/#gePE_87A58Q80T9rAAAA' },
  acks: {},
  connected: true,
  disconnected: false,
  handshake:
   { headers:
      { host: 'localhost:3000',
        connection: 'keep-alive',
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (K
HTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36',
        accept: '*/*',
        referer: 'http://localhost:3000/',
        'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, sdch',
        'accept-language': 'ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4',
        cookie: 'io=Evc9ZXFabxXte1XXAAAB' },
     time: 'Tue Sep 13 2016 17:25:34 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Summer Time)',
     address: '::1',
     xdomain: false,
     secure: false,
     issued: 1473780334962,
     url: '/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LSa9q5d',
     query: { EIO: '3', transport: 'polling', t: 'LSa9q5d' } } }
```

Any idea why this is not working?

Comment: `promisfyAll` is for standard async callbacks, not event emitter handlers. Using a promise probably doesn't make sense in this case anyways, since `io.on('connection')` will fire every time a client connects, not just once.

Comment: @dvlsg Thanks as well. Just needed to understand promise concept better. Coz I was trying to solve callback hell with them, and thought that this can be applied to anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use Bluebird's `.promisifyAll()` for common event handlers such as `.on()` for a variety of reasons.

1. The event handler can be called more than once.  Promises only resolve once.
2. `.promisifyAll()` requires an async operation where the last argument is a node.js calling style function with a signature such as `fn(err, data)`.  The `.on()` method does not follow that convention.

The likely reason it goes right to the `.catch()` handler is that your first argument is non-null which makes Bluebird thinks it has an error (per the above calling convention that it expects).

---

Promises are not an appropriate match for event handlers that can be called more than once.  Because the promise will only ever resolve once, you can only ever get one notification for an event using a promise.  For regular event handlers, promises are not recommended - use callbacks.

Comment: To be honest, I was trying to avoid callback hell by the means of promises.
But your answer made it clear for me. Thanks!